# Check if profile is admin or user and display accordingly

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

I am trying to display information based on role of user's login. If user is *admin* then display all the data from database and if other *user* then display only his details.

I tried this for **/profile** route after auth login

```
//get user details of login profile
router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res, data) =>{  
    User.find(req.userData, function(err, users) {
        if (req.role === "admin") {
        return res.json(users);
        }else{
        res.send(req.userData);
        }
  });
});
```

The `if` condition is not working here  `if (req.role === "admin")`
Only `res.send(req.userData);` is working over here.

I have already mentioned the role in `/login`

```
const adminEmail = "xyz@xyz.com";                                               
    const role = user[0].email===adminEmail? "admin" : "user";                                  
    const token = jwt.sign( 
    {
        email: user[0].email,
        userId: user[0]._id,
        phoneNo: user[0].phoneNumber,
        role
    }
```

In response I am getting

```
{
    "email": "xyz@xyz.com",
    "userId": "5c2dee17ea4264a40156f0",
    "phoneNo": "8xxx25",
    "role": "admin",
    "iat": 1547111673,
    "exp": 1547115273
}
```

Comment: role is in req object?or req.userData.role ?

Comment: @BittuS It's in `userData` . I tried this but getting blank array [ ]

Comment: if userData is empty,then how you are getting userData in response res.send(req.userData)?codes are missing i think

Comment: @BittuS userData is not empty. I am decoding my request over userData. I have corrected this now  `router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res) =>{  
 if (req.userData.role === "admin") { 
  User.find({}, function(err, users) {
   res.json(users);
  });
        }else{
        res.send(req.userData); 
        }
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to check role in `req`, but it is `undefined`. First you have to check if user is logged up. Then, if user is admin, get some data from database. Otherwise, send user's object.

```
router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res, data) =>{ 
    //  if req.userData is user object
    if(req.userData.role === 'admin') {
        User
        .find()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(error => res.json({error}))
    } else {
        res.json(req.userData);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it in this way

```
router.get('/profile', checkAuth, (req, res) =>{  
    if (req.userData.role === "admin") { 
        User.find({}, function(err, users) {
            res.json(users);
       });
    }else{
        res.send(req.userData); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a `user[0]`??

It should be `user["email"]` or `user.email` directly.

Given your response a single object and not an array of objects.

Comment: It's for current user . Working either way, it's in single object only. And if I mention in this way  `user.email` i won't be getting email and other details back in response.

Comment: Thanks for updating the comment and clarifying. I got confused earlier.